# Intel 82540EM is not getting bind with DPDK driver

Tags: dpdk

I am using dpdk library to enhance packet capturing. To use dpdk, we need to bind at least one NIC to dpdk driver. As written in dpdk documentation, I can either use uio_pci_generic or igb_ko driver.

To bind with dpdk driver, they have provided a python script:
http://www.dpdk.org/browse/dpdk/plain/tools/dpdk_nic_bind.py

I have two intel NIC's in my system, Intel 82579LM and Intel 82540EM. As given at http://dpdk.org/doc/nics , Intel 82540EM is a supported NIC with driver e1000.

Now, the problem is that I am unable to bind **Intel 82540EM** with dpdk drivers. I did the following steps:

1. ifdown INTERFACE_NAME
2. modprobe uio_pci_generic (or insmod igb_ko)
3. dpdk_nic_bind.py --bind=uio_pci_generic PCI_ID_OF_NIC

This prints an error **'Error: bind failed for PCI_ID_OF_NIC  - Cannot bind to driver uio_pci_generic'**. So I tried to bind it manually. I did the following steps to bind NIC manually:

1. ifdown INTERFACE_NAME
2. modprobe uio_pci_generic (or insmod igb_ko)
3. echo "PCI_ID_OF_NIC" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/e1000/unbind
4. echo "PCI_ID_OF_NIC" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/uio_pci_generic/bind

Even then I get **'bash: echo: write error: No such device'** error. I tried the same steps with Intel 82579LM, and it binded perfectly, but unfortunately it ain't a supported NIC.

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT update based on the comment request for `Output of lspci -vnnk 01:02.0`]

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller [8086:100e] (rev 02) 
Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:002e] 
Kernel driver in use: e1000 
Kernel modules: e1000 

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04) 
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:052c] Kernel driver in use: e1000e 
Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Comment: show output of `lspci -nk` regarding to your card BDF.

Comment: Output of lspci -vnnk



01:02.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: **Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller** [8086:100e] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter [8086:002e]
 Kernel driver in use: e1000
 Kernel modules: e1000

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:052c]
 Kernel driver in use: e1000e
 Kernel modules: e1000e

Comment: It's not readable, please update the post, and put the actual values instead of PCI_ID_OF_NIC in current post as well.

Comment: DPDK test for  Intel 82540EM is through `emulated NIC`. I have success in using emulated NIC. Offical supported NIC are `http://doc.dpdk.org/guides-20.02/nics/igb.html?highlight=known%20issues` and emulated NIC `https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/e1000em.html`. Can you share if this is emulated or physical NIC?

Comment: @user2914066 do you have updates to share? as shared in the above command I am able to get it working in qemu. Hence I have to assume this is more with configuration or settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have success in using emulated NIC with DPDK using igb_uio and uio_pci_generic. Details shared below.

- NIC with igb_uio: Sucess
- NIC with uio_pci_generic: Sucess
- Intel 82540EM: emulated NIC in Virtual machine
- DPDK version: stable-18.11.6
- test application: l2fwd
- cmd: `./build/l2fwd -w [pcie bdf of the NIC in VM] -- -p 0x1 -T 1`

By using full PCIe [S:B:D:F] ie `echo "0000:00:19.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/e1000/unbind` works for me

Answer (score 0):

DPDK provides 3 different drivers for userspace networking. Some NICs won't work with the `igb_uio_generic` or the `vfio-pci` and might only be supported by the `igb_uio` driver.

This driver is no longer in the DPDK main tree, so you'll need to grab it from `http://git.dpdk.org/dpdk-kmods/` instead